# C# MVVM pattern instance maintainance issue silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

we are developing a project with silverlight using c# MVVM pattern. We are using a custom-control inside a page. The custom-control raising some events based on its dependency property change that is working fine when am using new ViewModel instance for the same page.

Because of our business need we have to maintain the ViewModel instance for a page, at the same time we are not maintaining the page instance , so every time the page instance is created again.

Now If any property changed in particular view model whenever the particular page opened more than one time( closed then re-open) View model commands (events of the custom control) are being raised more than once per single property change.

I can understand that the view or custom control's previous instance remains somewhere and responds to the corresponding view model's property change. What is the best way to resolve this problem?

```
// my custom control
public class CustomControl:Control
{
    public event EventHandler SearchCompletedEvent;
    public bool IsSearch
    {
        get{return (bool)GetValue(IsSearchProperty)};
        set{SetValue(IsSearchProperty,value)};
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsSearch.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSearchProperty=
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsSearch", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsSearchPropertyChanged)));

    private static void OnIsSearchPropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject dp, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs de)
    {
        if (dp != null && dp is CustomControl&& de.NewValue != null)
        ((CustomControl)dp).OnIsSearchPropertyChanged((bool)de.NewValue);
    }
    private void OnIsSearchPropertyChanged(bool newValue)
    {
        if( newValue)
        {
            // some searching statements here
            if(SearchCompletedEvent!=null)
            SearchCompletedEvent(this,new EventArgs());      
        }
    }
}

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Func<bool> canExecute;
    private Action executeAction;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;  
    public RelayCommand(Action executeAction, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        this.executeAction = executeAction;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    } 

    public RelayCommand(Action executeAction)
    {
        this.executeAction = executeAction;
        this.canExecute = () => true;
    } 

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
        {
            CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    } 

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return canExecute == null ? true : canExecute();
    }
}        

//
//My ViewModel is like 
public class MainPageViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        SearchCommand=new RelayCommand(SearchEventMethod);
        FindCommand=new RelayCommand(FindMethod);
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ICommand SearchCommand{get;set;}
    public ICommand FindCommand{get;set;}
    private bool isSearch;
    public bool IsSearch
    {
        get { return isSearch;}
        set { isSearch=value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsSearch");
        }
    }

    private void SearchEventMethod()
    {
        IsSearch=false;
        // some codes for execute after search
    }

    private void FindMethod()
    {
        IsSearch=true;
    }
}

//
// My ViewModel Insatance Maintainer 
public class InstanceMaintainer
{
    public string InstanceKey{get;}
    public object ViewModelInstance{get;}

    public InstanceMaintainer(string instanceKey,object Instance)
    {
        this.InstanceKey=instanceKey;
        this.ViewModelInstance=Instance;
    }
}

//
// my App.xaml.cs file
public class App:Application
{
    private static List<InstanceMaintainer> instanceList=new  List<InstanceMaintainer>();
    public static object GetInstance(string programKey)
    {
        if(programKey=="PGM001")
        {
            MyXamlPage page=new MyXamlPage();
            if(insatnceList.select(x=>x.InstanceKey).Containes(programKey))
            {
                page.DataContext=insatnce.where(x=>x.InstanceKey==programKey).FirstOrDefault().Instance;
            }
            else
            {
                MainPageViewModel vm=new MainPageViewModel();
                instanceList.Add(new InstanceMaintainer(programKey,vm);
                page.DataContext=vm;
            }
        }
    }
}

// My xaml page is like
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <local:CustomControl IsSearch="{Binding IsSearch,Mode=TwoWay}" 
        SearchCompletedEvent="{Binding SearchCommand,Mode=TwoWay}">
    </local:CustomControl>

    <Button Command="{Binding FindCommand,Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Grid>
```

In this scenario first time we open the particular program by

```
App.GetInstance("PGM001");
```

the page and click the button My CustomControl response one time. And i close the page again open the same program by the same method now the page is new and ViewModelInstance is old right? now i click the button CustomCOntrol response two, three and so on.because of the created Page instance is remaines somewhere and response for ViewModel property change.

Comment: Are you using any frameworks? Are you subscribing to events again and again? Could you post some code to clarify ?

Comment: Agreed with @Noctis - it sounds like you are re-subscribing to events.

Comment: Hi @Noctis  thanks for your interest. But its hard to explain by code. Can I explain by sketch the flow by image for your reference? -@sureshkumar sp

Comment: whichever works for you, but with what you gave, it's hard to help you atm ...

Comment: Hi @Noctis code added please find and check.

Comment: @sureshkumarsp: Which method in your code is executing more times than you think it should?

Answer (score 0):

Without a whole of lot of information (or code) to go on I am going to have to guess at the problem. With that said it is very likely that you have an event handler that is causing one of your view models to stick around longer than you anticipated.

Consider for a moment that the XAML is bound to view model `A` like this.

```
XAML -> VM-A
```

Now consider a scenario where view model `A` has subscribed to an event in view model `B`. `B` must hold a reference to `A` to be able to invoke the event handler. In this case `A` is said to be the delegate target and `B` is the source.

```
VM-B -> Delegate -> VM-A
```

So whenever an action occurs in Silverlight that causes the XAML to bind to a *new* instance of `A` then the XAML will typically unbind itself from the *old* instance like expected. But, `B` would still be holding a reference to `A` and that is why it is sticking around still receiving events from `B`. Going further, the *new* instance of `A` will likely also be subscribing to the same event on `B` so that `B` now has *two* instances of `A` in its multicast delegate chain. That would explain why you see the event handler execute more than once. And, by the way, `B` does not necessarily have to be another view model class. It could be anything really. The custom user control could be playing the role `B` as well.

I have to be honest. I *still* run into this situation occasionally while doing WPF and Silverlight work and I am constantly on guard for it. So yeah, this is an easy one to overlook.

What you need to do is tell `A` that it is no longer being used so that it can unsubscribe from any events it was listening for. I recommend that you read [Weak Event Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx) to introduce yourself to the idea of subscribing to events in such a way that you do *not* have to necessarily unsubscribe from when you are done. Some MVVM frameworks have mechanisms for doing this very thing.